# Delphi 7, Windows 7, event handler, re-entrent code

Tags: delphi, windows-7, event-handling

I've got some very old code (15+yr) that used to run ok, on older slower machines with older software versions. It doesn't work so well now because if fails a race condition. This is a general question: tell me why I should have known and expected the failure in this code, so that I can recognise the pattern in other code:

```
procedure TMainform.portset(iComNumber:word);
begin
windows.outputdebugstring(pchar('portset ' + inttostr(icomnumber)));

with mainform.comport do
try
    if open then open := False; // close port
    comnumber:=iComNumber;
    baud:=baudrate[baudbox.itemindex];
    parity:=pNone;
    databits:=8;
    stopbits:=1;
    open:=true;
    flushinbuffer;
    flushoutbuffer;
    if open then mainform.statusb.Panels[5].text:=st[1,langnum] {Port open}
      else mainform.statusb.Panels[5].text:=st[2,langnum]; {port set OK}
except
  on E: exception do begin
    windows.OutputDebugString('exception in portset');
    mainform.statusb.Panels[5].text:=st[3,langnum];
    beep;
    beep;
  end;
end;
windows.outputdebugstring('portset exit');
end;
```

Note that flushinbuffer is protected with EnterCriticalSection(); AFAIK Nothing else is protected, and AFAIK there are no message handling sections. **BUT**

When this code is called from a click event, it gets part way through, then is interupted by a paint event.

The only tracing I have done is with outputdebugstring. I can see the first string repeated on entry before the second string is shown on exit. Is that real, or is it an illusion?

The trace looks like this:

```
4.2595    [4680] graph form click event
4.2602    [4680] portset 1 'from click event handler'
4.2606    [4680] graph form paint event
4.2608    [4680] portset 1 'from paint event handler'
4.2609    [4680] portset exit

4.3373    [4680] portset exit
```

This is a race condition: The *paint event handler* of the form is called before the *click event handler* code finishes, which causes failures. Serial code is AsyncPro. No thread code. Yes, there is more code, no it doesn't do anything in particular before "portset 1" but it does write to a form before it gets there:

```
with graphform do begin
    if not waitlab.Visible then begin
       waitlab.visible:=true;
       waitprogress.position:=0;
       waitprogress.visible:=true;
       waitprogress.max:=214;
    end;
end;
mainform.Statusb.panels[5].text:=gcap[10,langnum];
```

Don't hold back: What is it doing wrong, what should I be looking for?

Comment: What exactly is a "paint event"? And what is the call stack inside that event? Is all code running on gui thread?

Comment: And is anything calling ProcessMessages?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Just a thought, but do you think it could be changes in the Windows API over the past 15 years? OS security measures introduced since then might have changed the threading model under which certain functions are executed. Just a stab in the dark...

Comment: @Sam No, the answer will be in the user's code

Comment: Did you had a look at the StackTrace on second call of portset? You should see, which part is calling portset again

Comment: So, where's the stack trace?

Comment: Also, why does code that responds to `WM_PAINT` call `portset`? Isn't that your fundamental problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard paint event cannot happen on its own, it can only be triggered by message retrieval.  So the only way the code you showed could be interrupted the way you describe is if either the Serial component itself, or an event handler you have assigned to it, is doing something that pumps the calling thread's message queue for new messages.

Comment: That is only partly true. Create a new VCL forms application and place a TButton and a TPaintBox on it. In the button click event call PaintBox1.Refresh. The paint event will get fired inside the button click event. You can test it with the debugger. (XE3)

Comment: This is why I asked for clarity on precisely what is meant by a "paint event".

Comment: `Refresh()` invalidates and then updates the control's window, triggering an immediate `WM_PAINT` message to be delivered to the window without going through the message queue. AsyncPro is a non-visual component, and AFAICS does not call `ProcessMessages()` (though it does rely on messages) or otherwise pump the message queue directly, hense my suggestion about an event handler possibly being at fault instead.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe and Remy Lebeau, there is a lack of clarity here. Uwe Raabe seems to suggest that an application will do implicit direct calls to event handlers, Remy Lebeau seems to suggest that an application can only do indirect calls by explicity pumping a message queue. Which is it?  (And explict calls, And by completing and returning control to the application message queue, those options are not the question)

Comment: @david: Uwe was saying that an app can manually invoke a paint operation immediately at any time, by calling `Refresh()` in code, without waiting for the message loop to invoke painting via posted messages. I was saying that it is unlikely that AsyncPro is doing something internally that directly causes pending messages to be processed, but it is possible that it could be triggering off an event handler into user code that then does something to cause either an immediately repaint or message processing to occur.

Answer (score 4):

This is expected behaviour - opening or closing a `TApdComPort` will service the message queue, specifically by calling a function it names `SafeYield`:

```
function SafeYield : LongInt;
    {-Allow other processes a chance to run}
  var
    Msg : TMsg;
  begin
    SafeYield := 0;
    if PeekMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) then begin
      if Msg.Message = wm_Quit then
        {Re-post quit message so main message loop will terminate}
        PostQuitMessage(Msg.WParam)
      else begin
        TranslateMessage(Msg);
        DispatchMessage(Msg);
      end;
      {Return message so caller can act on message if necessary}
      SafeYield := MAKELONG(Msg.Message, Msg.hwnd);
    end;
  end;
```

The `TApdComPort` is an async component - the com port is managed on background threads and opening or closing the port requires either starting or signaling those threads to stop.  While waiting for them to free the component services the message queue in case it takes some time for things to synchronize (for example) :

```
if Assigned(ComThread) then
begin
     {Force the comm thread to wake...}
     FSerialEvent.SetEvent;
     {... and wait for it to die}
     ResetEvent(GeneralEvent);
     while (ComThread <> nil) do
     SafeYield;
end;
```

You haven't really show us enough of your own code to say why this is problematic in your case, however.  I think David's point about com ports being manipulated in a paint handler is valid... we need to see the broader picture and what, exactly, the problem is that you are having.

Answer (score 1):

**Since you are closing the port in the beginning of your event handler, if there is any chance of triggering the event twice** (i.e. by calling `Application.ProcessMessages` anywhere from your code, or calling `TMainform.portset()` directly from a worker thread), **the new instance will close your port while the older one tries to communicate trough it**, which will result in an error. AFAIS there are two solutions:

- The *faster but least bearable* one is to protect your entire function with a Mutex (or event which is not a syncronisation object but can be used as one), but this only hides the coding error you have made.
- The *more pro solution* is to find where the race condition gets raised, then fix your code. You can do it by searching all references to `Application.ProcessMessages()` and `TMainform.portset()`, and make sure that they won't get called paralelly. If no reference can be found on either mentioned function, the problem could still be caused by running multiple instances of your code ('cause it will not create multiple com ports :) ).

Comment: A TCriticalSection won't help when the reentrance occurs in the same thread (by calling Application.ProcessMessages).

Comment: @Uwe Raabe - Thank you for pointing that out. (I was aware of it, but I failed to mention it in my answer.)

Comment: When you get something wrong, and it is pointed out, what you should do is edit the answer to correct it. Even when you do that, it's incorrect to say that an event is a mutual exclusion object. It is not. However, there's a bigger problem than all of that. Suppose you do wrap the function in a mutex. Then inside the function you make the re-entrant call. Now your thread is deadlocked.

Comment: Mutexes and critical sections are reentrant when entered by the same thread that already has obtained their lock.

Comment: You're not helping yourself by referencing GUI components during a COM Port operation. There's no good reason for you to be doing this and it's complicating the code and will generate the paint events you mention.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have fixed the error which I have left in my answer by pure politeness: now it is not clear what is wrong and why does Uwe Raabe complain. And could you point out where did I say that an event is a mutual exception object?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hmm, I was getting confused with mutex objects in other threading libraries. But you are right, Windows mutex is recursive.

Comment: @mg30rg You mean mutual exclusion I presume. So, if you are not suggesting the use of an event for that purpose, what are you suggesting? And finally, since as Remy points out, a mutex is recursive, what difference would it make to wrap the function in a mutex lock? Since this all runs on the same thread, either you deadlock if you have non-recursive mutual exclusion, or the mutual exclusion serves no purpose because the call is recursive on the same thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I meant mutual exclusion. English is not my native language, and to err is human. (To be verbally abusive is also.) Otherwise, you are telling me that if I put an event in a signaled state (or obtain ownership over a mutex) and I wait for it to be unsignaled (freed) will not make my function reentrancy-safe?Of course it could lead to a deadlock if the source is that bad,but  in that case a massive refactoring will be the only solution,and debugging will help finding the place to start... if you use an event instead of a mutex,the debugger will show the deadlocking point.

Comment: Nobody should be verbally abusive. Which is fine, because nobody here has been verbally abusive. Pointing out errors is not abusive. Remy pointed out an error that I made. Which is good. Waiting for an event won't stop code being re-entrant. And mutual exclusion cannot protect against re-entrant calls. Mutual exclusion prevents multiple threads executing the protected section. But in a case of re-entrancy there is only one thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Pointing out typos can be considered verbal aggression. Pointing out real errors, like when you are talking about "protection against re-entrant calls" can be better. Reentrancy is not an error in itself. Wrongly performed reentrancy can be an error. If you supervise your comment from this point of view, you will see it fails to mean anything significant.

Comment: I pointed out the two real errors in your first bullet. Now it's up to you to fix them.

Comment: I was talking about "@mg30rg You mean mutual exclusion I presume.".

Comment: No, you've not fixed the errors. First error is that wrapping the function in a mutual exclusion lock will do either: 1. Deadlock the thread if the lock is non-recursive, or 2. Make no change to the behaviour of the program if the lock is recursive.  The second error is that you state that re-entrancy can be suppressed by some unspecified use of an event. Perhaps an event could do something useful, but if so then you need to be specific about what that something is.

Answer (score 0):

Remy Lebeau gets the credit for answering the question, because, as I asked for, it was a general reply to a general question. But it would have been inadequate without his comments in response to Uwe Raabe.

And what conclusively demonstrated that Remy Lebeau was correct was the exceptional answer from J, pointing out the specific point where the code failed.

Thanks also to David Heffernan  for asking "why does code that responds to WM_PAINT call portset", which also makes a general point. And yes, the quick fix was just to block the path from the paint event handler to the comms code, but I'd done that without recognising the more general point.

I'll be having a look at the comms code, to see if there are more problems like this, and I'll be looking at the event handlers, to see if there are more problems like this, so thanks to everyone who read and considered the question.