# How to block other threads to use Synchronize if the main thread is not idle?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have a TListView in the main Form (Thread) and many other threads that add/delete item from the list using Synchronize method. But the main thread has also a method that modify the list items and I want that method not to be interrupted by other threads that wants to execute code in the main thread. Is this possible ?

Comment: The main thread can only be interrupted if you let it be interrupted. Are you doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have evidence that what you are worried about is happening?  You shouldn't, because it can't happen.  That is what `Synchronize` is for.  Methods executing in the main thread must complete before the main thread can service the message queue to process work items dispatched via `Synchronize` from worker threads so you have nothing to worry about.

When a worker thread uses `Synchronize` it essentially just posts a message to the main thread telling it that it has work for it to do.  If the main thread is busy executing another method then the worker thread will simply block until the main thread is finished, subsequently processes the message queue, picks up the work item, executes it, and then posts back to the worker thread that the work is complete (leaving the worker thread free to then continue).

This, of course, assuming that the method in your main thread is *not* calling `Application.ProcessMessages()` or `CheckSynchronize()` (or you are using a tricky component that does this, or something similar, without you knowing it -> see : [Delphi 7, Windows 7, event handler, re-entrent code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18095302/327083))

Comment: So, are you saying that when a worker thread call Synchronize, that code will be executed in the main thread only when the main thread has finished what it was doing ?

Comment: The main thread is more or less just waiting for a message and process it. Any event of say a form in Delphi is merely called in response to processing a message. An easy way to mess these things up is by calling Application.ProcessMessages inside such an event, which therefore should be avoided or better banned.

Comment: @marusnebunu Yes.  The main thread can only do one thing at a time.  If it is executing your method then it cannot also be checking for messages telling it that a thread has work for it to do. It does this when the current work is finished (this is why it is called a message loop - *check for work?  -> do work -> check for work? -> do work -> etc*).  `Application.ProcessMessages` will cause problems because this explicitly instructs the main thread to check for work (and do it) before continuing with the work it is already doing.  If you are not calling `ProcessMessages`, you are fine.